# How do I create a shortcut for task manager in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcuts

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Del</kbd>  to be the shortcut for `lxtask`. Also, my laptop keyboard have a key with the Windows logo, how do I configure it to open my `menu`?

Comment: 1:nothing happens. I'm using the long term support 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` for safety.

Open `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` with `leafpad` or with `nano` or any other plain text editor.

Search for this code:

```
<!-- Launch task manager on Ctrl + Alt + Del-->
<keybind key="C-A-Delete">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxsession-default tasks</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Very carefully, change `lxsession-default tasks` to `lxtask`.

Save the file (and exit the text editor if you want).

Open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure`. If you've done everything correctly (and if you haven't already messed up the file), you should just get back the terminal prompt.

Now, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, the task manager should open.